# Como embaralhar uma lista de objetos através de um valor padrão?

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
public class Object{
    public String ID{get;set;}
}
```

E em um momento no meu código eu recebo uma lista deles:

```
List<Object> objs = new List<Object>();
objs.add(new Object{ID = "1"});
objs.add(new Object{ID = "2"});
objs.add(new Object{ID = "3"});
objs.add(new Object{ID = "4"});
```

E depois eu randomizo os objetos:

```
objs = objs.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
Debug.WriteLine(objs.ID);
// 1 4 2 3
```

Se eu executar `objs.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();` vou receber uma ordem totalmente aleatória `// 3 2 4 1`.

Preciso passar uma "seed"(um número inteiro) e randomizar em relação a ele, por exemplo, se eu passo o numero 1 e recebo `// 3 2 4 1`, quando eu executar o numero 1 de novo eu preciso receber a mesma ordem.

Existe algum recurso no c# para fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de usar GUID dentro do método [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2) use o  método [`Random.Next(int maxValue)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_) de um objeto [Random](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) instanciado pelo constructor [`Random(int seed)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_), assim que gerando a mesma sequencia de números pseudo-aleatórios a cada seed.

**Exemplo:**

```
var rand = new Random(4);
var ListaEmbaralhada = Lista.OrderBy(a => rand.Next(Lista.Count)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe sim. O `Random` aceita essa seed que você estava a falar. Se você iniciar sempre com o mesmo valor ele produzirá sempre a mesma sequência.

```
var r = new Random(4);
var list = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i){
    var idx = r.Next(list.Count);
    var aux = list[idx];
    list[idx] = list[i];
    list[i] = aux;
}
list.Dump();
```